# What is the best resolution of the Android images for Tablet and normal devices?

Tags: android

I am developing application that will run on normal android device and on 7 inch Tablet and I have slider of images and I want to know what is the best resolution of the images that I should use for this application ?

Comment: for tablet you can use 620*1024 images.. nd resolution is depend on device

Answer (score 0):

It depends on

1. How big u want to image to show up
2. Your device densities in your "Normal Device" and you 7" tablets

Comment: my image will fill width of screen - 50dp left - 50 dp right and height about quarter of screen

Answer (score 0):

it really depends on lots of things as @Naresh mentions, but as far as i know Nexus 10 (2560*1600) has the biggest resolution for 10 inch tablets and for 7 inch 1440*900 seems the biggest one and 1280*800 also very common, as mentioned below link
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_tablet_computers#5.E2.80.938.C2.A0in_.2813.E2.80.9320.C2.A0cm.29_screen

Answer (score 0):

put images under folder the following folders:

As per the documentation-
drawable-sw600-mdpi : resolution (600 * 1024 )
drawable-sw600-hdpi : resolution(900 * 1536)

hdpi resolution : (mdpi resolution) * 1.5
xhdpi resolution : (mdpi resolution) * 2

resolution also depends on the factors mentioned by Naresh.